# Understanding Code in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
public static void mystery2d(int[][] a) {
    for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < a[0].length - 1; c++) {
            if (a[r][c + 1] > a[r][c]) {
                a[r][c] = a[r][c + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If a two-dimensional array named numbers is initialized to store the following integers, what are its contents after the call shown?

```
int[][] numbers = {
    {3, 4, 5, 6},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
    {5, 6, 7, 8}
};
mystery2d(numbers);
```

I am really trying to understand code with 2D list but am having difficulties following along through the for loops. If someone could walk me through the steps or explain to me how it works that would be great thank you very much!

For example what would be a the values of the code bellow so I could have something to see if I could see the iterations of the loop better?

```
numbers[0][0] = ??
numbers[1][1] = ??
numbers[2][3] = ??
```

Comment: Try solving school assignments on your own to be a better programmer.

Comment: This code can throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is to remove the smallest element in each row.
This is how it works.

In First row, it will check if 3<4? It is true. So, the a[0]=3 is replaced as a[0]=4 but a[1]=4 remains same. The same procedure happens till it reaches the end of each row. So the number in the last position at the end of every 'c'th iteration remains same.

Hence, the Output will be :

4566
5677
6788

So, the smallest element in each row. i.e. 3,4,5 in 1st, 2nd and 3rd row respectively is removed from array. I hope you got something!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should use i and j in your for loops rather than r and c, it is good practice. Your loop compares one number with the next number and changes the original to the new number if the new is greater than the original. So numbers[0][0] would be compared 3 ? 4 = 3 < 4 = so the 3 now becomes a 4. numbers[1][1] would be 5 ? 6 = 5 < 6 = 5 now becomes 6. And so on. Hope this helps.

Comment: I must add, that I completely agree with Apurva. If this is for school, you should definitely ask your teacher for help. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, this is the `condition` not the `loop` that compares number with the next one.

Comment: True, sorry for that. Thanks.